# Galton/Plinko Board Manipulations - Theoretical Question

Tags: probability-theory

I am familiar with a "Galton Board"/Plinko board basically illustrating the central limit theorem. What would happen if:

1. I changed the distribution of pegs on the board?
2. I changed the "incoming distribution" of slots in which I drop the balls on top?

In both cases what would be the resulting distribution be? Could I achieve a non-gaussian distribution at the output by manipulating either(both) the input distribution and the pegs?

Clarification: Could I select a distribution of pegs giving me an arbitrary output distribution?

Note: This was originally posted on math.stackexchange.com but deleted and posted here. After reviewing both sites mission statements, I felt it was better suited here.

Comment: Your "clarification" question was addressed in the MO question,"[Ping-pong relief map of a given function z=f(x,y)](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69635/)," and was partially answered there by Gerhard Paseman.

Answer (score 1):

> Could I achieve a non-gaussian distribution at the output
>   by manipulating either(both) the input distribution and the pegs?

Yes you could pack the pegs so closely that the ball cannot fit between them and is forced to the extreme left or right bin.  Or you could remove all pegs and then the balls would all go into the middle bin.  These ball distributions would not be gaussian.

Comment: thank you. What I meant was more along the lines of: In principle, could I select a distribution of pegs giving me an arbitrary output distribution?

Comment: user79950, my guess is that one way to bias the result is to use oval rather than round pins, and then change their orientation from vertical to some other angle.  Now generalize that ovals to lengths of metal (or plastic) in arbitrary shapes.  Send the balls wherever you want!  I think in this way you could approximate a wide variety of distributions.  However, I don't think this answer will be satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

> Clarification: Could I select a distribution of pegs
>   giving me an arbitrary output distribution?

According to the internet, this code implements such a construction:
https://github.com/sirosen/biased-galtonbox